# PHPMailer: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, smtp

Estou fazendo envios autenticados, porém é estranho que as vezes envia normalmente, e outras ocorre a falha. O cliente insiste que no servidor dele está tudo correto, e agora já estou sem argumentos. A versão que uso é a 5.2.8, alguém teria alguma sugestão?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = $email_host;
$mail->Port = $email_port; //587
$mail->Username = $email_send;
$mail->Password = $email_pass;
$mail->setFrom($email_send, 'Site');
$mail->addAddress($destino);

if ($mail->send())
{
    echo 'Enviado';
}
else
{
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: pode postar o erro que é mostrado?

Comment: Parece que foi resolvido o problema, mas anteriormente a mensagem era de "SMTP connect() failed"